# biblatex 2.8 manual mistypeset

Tags: biblatex

Is there an easy way to report problems of this sort?  The Biblatex 2.8 manual, as distributed by TeX Live Utility on my mac from CTAN, has none of the references to to other sections or to pages resolved.  One is referred to page ?? and section ??.  Obviously the manual should have been pdflatexed multiple times, but wasn't.

But there does not seem to be an obvious reporting channel for such problems.
The authors of the manual do not advertise their email addresses.

Comment: Issues with `biblatex` (as maintained by PLK/AB/JAW) can be reported at https://github.com/plk/biblatex/issues. This one's already known: PLK is already sorting it out!

Answer (score 2):

This is fixed on CTAN and will be pushed into TL shortly.